# Sails.js: how to Join multiple models using waterline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've 3 models Continent,Country and city. I'd like to join these models to get the results.

### Continent.js

```
attributes: {

continent_Id:{

    type:'string',
    primaryKey: true


},
continent_Name:{

    type:'string'
},
description:{

 type:'string'

},
country:{
        collection: 'country',
        via: 'continent'
}
```

}

### Country.js

```
attributes: {

country_Id:{

    type:'string',
    primaryKey: true
},

countryName:{

    type:'string'
},

description:{

  type:'string'

},

continent:{
        model:'continent'
    },

 languages:{

    collection:'Country_language',
    via:'country'
 },

 city:{

    collection:'city',
    via:'country'

 }
}
```

city.js

```
attributes: {

city_Id:{

    type:'string',
    primaryKey:true
},

cityName:{

 type:'string'

},

description:{

 type:'string'

},

country:{

    model:'country'
}
```

Now I can get the results by using Model.query :

```
var query = 'select a.continent_Name,b.countryName,c.cityName from continent a inner join country b on a.continent_id = b.continent inner join city c on b.country_Id = c.country';

Continent.query(query,function(err,data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

and the result is:

[ { continent_Name: 'ASIA',
    countryName: 'India',
    cityName: 'Delhi' } ]

Is there any way to get the same results by using 'waterline' query like

```
 Continent.find().populate().where({}).exec(function(err,data){
   console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: So you have gotten as far as creating three models with associations to each other, including a model (`Country`) that has associations to _both_ other models.  Are you really stumped about how to write a Waterline query that will link all the results together, or have you just not really tried?  I'll give you a hint:  you can call `populate` multiple times, for different associations.

Comment: The snark is unnecessary, but @sgress454 is right. RTFM and use populate for each model or `populateAll()`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes I know that I can join the table with populate(). but I need something like this https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/112 Country.join(Continent,cb);

Comment: any update on this? [this link](https://github.com/treelinehq/waterline-sql-builder/blob/master/docs/syntax.md#join-methods) provides some documentation about joins but not sure whether they are available and how to use them